# Is full_access_as_app mandatory for to send email using EWS application by using OAuth

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, oauth, exchangewebservices

I have application which uses EWS with basic authentication. As mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth). I'm trying to get away from basic authentication and use OAuth.

I want to know if it is mandatory to have full_access_as_app  or I would be able to send emails if only Mail.Send permission is granted in azure?

Note : My application just wants to send email. Right now I'm getting 401 error and azure have only Mail.Send permission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, EWS is a legacy API so doesn't support the more constrained permission that the Graph supports. If your app only sends email why not just migrate it to the Graph the Auth will be same and its really just one API call to send an email and you app will be a lot more secure.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not able to find link on how to migrate to MS graph from EWS. Any pointers? Also how big that effort would be?

Comment: If you app just sends email then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp would be where I would start. The Authentication part is going to be the most work, once that is done the example in that link should be able to replace your EWS code.